# Custom headers in Phantomjs Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

According to [this](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/pull/229) it is possible now to modify headers. Atm i need to modify Accept-Language in PhantomJS webdriver. This code doesn't work

```
DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Accept-Language'] = 'ru-RU'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

Is it possible somehow to configure Phantomjs to send my header? i don't care where: inside ghostdriver, phantomjs or phantomjs-webdriver.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The latest version ([1.9.1](https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/downloads/list)) of PhantomJS is release Jun/5/2013. The pull request is merged [Jun/23/2013](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/commit/43a8fbcb6cbe55c459b659e44a61858ef1169a71).

If you are using 1.9.1 version of PhantomJS, custom headers will not work.

You have to build phantomjs yourself or wait until phantomjs merge ghostdriver changes and release new version.

- Clone PhantomJS repository
- Clone ghostdriver repository
- copy ghostdriver/src/* to phantomjs/src/ghostdriver recursively
- build phantomjs

Using newly build phantomjs I got following result:

```
from selenium import webdriver

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Accept-Language'] = 'ru-RU'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://httpbin.org/headers')
print(driver.page_source)
```

---

```
...
{
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "close",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.10.0 (development) Safari/534.34",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
  }
 ...
```

### UPDATE

Use PhantomJS *1.9.2+*.

Comment: thanks this worked for me but not with Javascript. `print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.language"))`. Does it work for you? // @dimazubrik

Comment: @Neil, It's a different thing. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage.language

Answer (score 2):

I write a full example to set all headers , window size and proxy in selenium phantomjs:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def init_phantomjs_driver(*args, **kwargs):

    headers = { 'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }

    for key, value in headers.iteritems():
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.{}'.format(key)] = value

    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'

    driver =  webdriver.PhantomJS(*args, **kwargs)
    driver.set_window_size(1400,1000)

    return driver


def main():
    service_args = [
        '--proxy=127.0.0.1:9999',
        '--proxy-type=http',
        '--ignore-ssl-errors=true'
        ]

    driver = init_phantomjs_driver(service_args=service_args)

    driver.get('http://cn.bing.com')
```

#### Note:

`userAgent` is set in `phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent` instead of `phantomjs.page.customHeaders`

Comment: Weird thing.. but, this stopped working for me now. :|